# How to change the Caffeine icons in panel when using the Elementary theme

Tags: 10.10, icons, elementary-theme

When I use the Elementary theme 2.0 the default Caffeine icon is displayed in my top-panel. I found some [nice icons](http://0rax0.deviantart.com/art/Caffeine-mono-MegaPack-169089645) that’ll fit the theme better. I followed the instructions on the page and they’re not working for me. Any tips how I can make these icons show up in my panel?

Comment: Your link isn't working, is there any chance you could post a different link?

Comment: Yes weird… I’ll give you the devianART page instead http://0rax0.deviantart.com/art/Caffeine-mono-MegaPack-169089645?q=&qo=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay… I found a solution.

What I did is:

- Renamed both icons to `caffeine-cup-empty.svg` and `caffeine-cup-full.svg`
- Since I use the dark variant of Elementary I sudo copied both icons to `/usr/share/icons/elementary-mono-dark/status/22`
- Then I refreshed my icon cache by typing:
  `sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/elementary-mono-dark/`

It seems to do the trick, I have no idea or this is how things are suppose to be done though.

Comment: mark this as this answer to your question so the question won't show as open.